# MAUI: How can I change the title bar color on macOS?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

[image]

How to change the title bar color on .NET MAUI (.NET 7.0)?

I've changed styles.xaml, colors.xaml, shell color but none of these things worked well, there are many questions like this but none of them aim at macOS, so neither worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible on macOS and as such this is also not possible with .NET MAUI. The API for the `UITitleBar` can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uititlebar?language=objc

You can hide it and do some other things, but not really give it a color.

What you might want to try is hide and and put something in it's place, but you will have a hard time mimicking all the macOS operations one can do like closing, minimizing, dragging the window etc.